# RROR: Command errored out with exit status 1 Python

Tags: python

I am installing packages from requirments.txt file using this command

> pip install -r C:\Users\MSI\Desktop\pddSpider-master\requirements.txt
> it returns after installing some packages:

```
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\msi\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\MSI\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-i3ladjxy\\cffi_d7086d7149244c569b1d283214caf323\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\MSI\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-i3ladjxy\\cffi_d7086d7149244c569b1d283214caf323\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\MSI\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-sdkc1qs8'
         cwd: C:\Users\MSI\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-i3ladjxy\cffi_d7086d7149244c569b1d283214caf323\
    Complete output (19 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\MSI\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-i3ladjxy\cffi_d7086d7149244c569b1d283214caf323\setup.py", line 120, in <module>
        if sys.platform == 'win32' and uses_msvc():
      File "C:\Users\MSI\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-i3ladjxy\cffi_d7086d7149244c569b1d283214caf323\setup.py", line 98, in uses_msvc
        return config.try_compile('#ifndef _MSC_VER\n#error "not MSVC"\n#endif')
      File "c:\users\msi\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\command\config.py", line 225, in try_compile
        self._compile(body, headers, include_dirs, lang)
      File "c:\users\msi\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\command\config.py", line 132, in _compile
        self.compiler.compile([src], include_dirs=include_dirs)
      File "c:\users\msi\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 327, in compile
        self.initialize()
      File "c:\users\msi\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 224, in initialize
        vc_env = _get_vc_env(plat_spec)
      File "c:\users\msi\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 314, in msvc14_get_vc_env
        return _msvc14_get_vc_env(plat_spec)
      File "c:\users\msi\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 268, in _msvc14_get_vc_env
        raise distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError(
    distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
    ----------------------------
```

---

Comment: Please read the error. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Check your Microsoft Visual C++ version and upgrade it to version 14.0 or above.

Comment: can you guide me?